# Is there a way to clearly identify text meant in jest?

Tags: jokes, emotions, emoticons

In written text, it can be difficult to convey the appropriate sentiment.  For example, if I tell someone to *"go fly a kite"*, I could say this with a smile and/or wink in person and they would know I'm joking.  **Is there an accepted way to convey the intended sentiment via written text, particularly via e-mail?**

I often see the smilie face emoticon :) or :-) or ;) associated with comments that are meant without offence/offense ;).

Is the emoticon the best/only way we have to communicate a comment intended to be taken in jest?

*Note: This may be in the context of a formal e-mail to a group, where the intent of the jest is to disarm an emotionally charged topic/situation.  The question is not in regards to what 12-year olds are using to convey jest via acronyms in text messaging.*

Comment: I find the safest approach is to never, ever write anything in jest.

Comment: Adding "lol" (laugh out loud) is a common trick to convey humor.

Comment: @surlawda - Except that I've rarely found that there is anything funny in the vicinity of an "lol" notation.

Comment: @HotLicks a safe approach indeed.  I seem incapable of taking that safe approach, so looking for a strategy to limit the risk of misinterpretation.

Comment: (Hint:  Consider jest what I said above.)

Comment: @HotLicks Without an associated lol or a smilie face I couldn't be sure.  I do appreciate your help making the point.

Comment: @HotLicks No doubt. But isn't that the same with an emoticon? There is nothing inherently funny about "go fly a kite,' so the emoticon is used to indicate that it's not to be taken seriously. More to the point, you rightly recognize that what you can convey in spoken language is harder to get across in email--so really, you just have to know your reader. My friends know when I'm joking without additional explanation; if I'm writing to a business contact, not so much. It's all about context.

Comment: Are you certain this isn't a [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) question?

Comment: @surlawda I agree with you about the potential risk of explaining that something is intended as funny.  Slapping lol or :) does not a funny comment make (and may be seen as insincere). I think your comments about the issue further make the point of the question.  I suppose there is always comic sans.

Comment: You can write in parentheses what that smile and/or wink (and/or 'nudge, nudge') in person means. For example: *Go fly a kite! (Don't take offense, I am speaking facetiously)* or *(I mean that in a friendly way)* or *(I'm just joking/kidding).*

Comment: In tech/nerd circles some use a `</sarcasm>` tag at the end of a sarcastic sentence (see the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%3C%2Fsarcasm%3E) and a [ThinkGeek tshirt](https://www.thinkgeek.com/product/e58f/) for examples). Of course, the meaning would likely be lost to those not familiar with HTML/XML.

Comment: This is not a question about the English language.

Comment: One option is to invoke the name of a comedian, something like "As Henny Youngman might say, Take my wife, please!"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain what our statisticians think about this, but according to my observations, people who have no sense of humor constitute about one half of the human race. Of those, many are touchy and not particularly bright. Thus, absolutely anything, humorous or not, can get misconstrued in an email, or even in a live conversation, no matter how much you smile or wink, no matter how many reassuring gestures you make, etc.

Ergo, to be PERFECTLY safe from morons whose mission in life is to cavil at anything and everything one says, one would need to keep silent at all times. Find a mountain cave and become a hermit, or talk only to birds, like St. Francis.

That said, you could explain that you're about to make a joke beforehand; or make the joke and then explain that you were being humorous (or *facetious*, as the Philistines say these days). The former is a notch safer than the latter: it preempts the addressee's taking offense; the latter comes off more like an apology when offense has already been taken.

For instance, you could say **before** making a joke:

"As the famous poet said in jest to his beloved ... "

... and "Just kidding" or "I'm being facetious, please don't take it seriously **after**.

Alternatively, you could conclude the email with "F... you if you can't take a joke," but that doesn't always work to everyone's satisfaction.

Answer (score -1):

Marking your text as being meant in jest sort of takes away from the hilarity of it anyway.
"Go frack yourself, lol jk." isn't really very funny and is sort of just offensive. It's sort of like saying something, and right after saying "just kidding" before the person responds.

The only way I think it can truly work, is if you know the person, and they know that you often express things in jest. But that's not really conveying it within the text itself.